# SwiftUI integer specifier didn't work in picker

Tags: swiftui

I tried to make my selection into 2 decimal place. But all my selection become 0.00. Is it the bug of SwiftUI or something? iOS 14.2

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    @State var i = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Picker(selection: $selectedIndex, label: Text("Select Number")){
                    ForEach(1..<5) {i in
//                        Text("\(i, specifier: "%.2f")") // display 0.00
                        Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", i))") // display 0.00
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you wanted

```
Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", Float(i)))").tag(i)   // or Double
```

[image: demo1]

[image: demo2]